# Agrupar Linhas de uma Array - PHP

Tags: php, array

Tenho uma consulta SQL que retorna um conjunto de valores:

```
cod_Vd  nome_Vend   cod_eqp nome_equipe
  46    46 - EVANDRO    1   EQUIPE -01
  87    87 - ALAN       1   EQUIPE -01
  44    44 - ANA        2   EQUIPE - 02
  84    84 - JORGEVAL   2   EQUIPE - 02
```

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma função ou lógica no PHP que organize uma *array* com estes dados da seguinte forma:

```
1   EQUIPE -01
46  46 - EVANDRO
87  87 - ALAN

2   EQUIPE - 02
44  44 - ANA 
84  84 - JORGEVAL
```

Segue exemplo resumido do código que eu tentei:

```
$arrayVendedores = array_unique($arrayVendedoresConsultaSQL);

foreach($arrayVendedores as $value) {

      echo($value["equipeVendedor"]);

}

foreach($arrayVendedores as $valueDois) {

    if($value["equipeVendedor"]==$valueDois["equipeVendedor"]) {

         echo($valueDois["nome_vendedor"]);

    }

}
```

Resultado:

```
1   EQUIPE - 01
46  46 - EVANDRO
87  87 - ALAN
1   EQUIPE - 01
46  46 - EVANDRO
87  87 - ALAN
2   EQUIPE - 02
44  44 - ANA 
84  84 - JORGEVAL
2   EQUIPE - 02
44  44 - ANA 
84  84 - JORGEVAL
```

Answer (score 0):

Você terá que organizar a array na mão mesmo, criando lógica completa. 
Jeito mais fácil e com maior custo para o banco seria ir pesquisando aos poucos.
Exemplo: Faz select da equipe 01 com order by de número e pegar array.
Depois faz select da equipe 02 igual equipe 01, pega o array e dar um array merge com a array da equipe 01 e assim sucessivamente.

Ou você pode fazer trazer tudo de uma vez só com order by de equipe criar lógica dentro do foreach. Exemplo:

```
$arrayOrganizado = new array();
foreach ($resultados as $row){
  if (!isset($arrayOrganizado[$value["equipeVendedor"]]) {
     $arrayOrganizado[$value["equipeVendedor"]][] = $valor;
  }

}
```

Usar os índices para organizar os dados.